# how to call this Prolog code inside java netbeans

Tags: netbeans, prolog

```
/* medical diagnostic system

start with ?- check.
*/   

check:-
    checkfor(Disease),
    write('I believe you have '),
    write(Disease),
    nl,
    undo.

/* disease to be checked */   

checkfor(cold):- cold.

/* cold */

cold:-
    checkSymptom(a),
    checkSymptom(b),
    checkSymptom(c),
    nl.

askQuestion(Question):-
    write('Do you have the Symptom '),
    write(Question),
    write('?'),
    read(Reply),
    nl,
    ( (Reply == yes ; Reply == y)
    -> assert(yes(Question))
    ; assert(no(Question)), fail
    ).

:- dynamic yes/1,no/1.

checkSymptom(S) :-
    ( yes(S)
    -> true
    ; ( no(S)
      -> fail
      ; askQuestion(S)
      )
    ).

undo :- retract(yes(_)), fail.
undo :- retract(no(_)), fail.
undo.
```

Comment: Pleasse post some examples of what you have tried so far.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "How to run Prolog in the Netbeans IDE?" or "How to call Prolog from a Java program?"

Comment: I want to create a gui to run this program in netbeans IDE

Comment: I don't have any examples

Comment: I think you're going to be out of luck, it seems Netbeans IDE doesn't have much in the way of support for Prolog. You can run whichever dialect of Prolog you have installed from the command-line, so Power Shell (windows) or terminal (MacOS/Linux). If you're not comfortable with the command-line, you can use SWISH, [I setup the program for you](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/57932682/how-to-call-this-prolog-code-inside-java-netbeans.pl), just query with `check.`

Comment: Thank you i create the interface by direct coding in prolog..